# Does the gem 'rails-settings-cached' allow multiple setting model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, settings

We were using 'rails-settings-cached' gem successfully in our project. But now we want to have usergroup based settings. So we will have a different setting model for that.
When I run following code, as explained in [documentation](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached/blob/master/README.md),

```
rails g settings:install UsersGroupSettings
```

I get following result:-

```
create  app/models/users_group_settings.rb
    conflict  config/app.yml
Overwrite /Users/username/workspace/project/config/app.yml? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip  config/app.yml
   identical  db/migrate/20180127071424_create_settings.rb
```

which led me to thinking that what I am trying to do might not be possible using this gem (creating multiple setting models). Is it possible to create multiple setting models like this?

Comment: This line from the documentation makes me think that the gem is not intended for the use you want: `a table of global key, value pairs`

Comment: @WizardofOgz But the gem allows settings to be extended to models https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached#extend-a-model